# Heroku does not recognize relative imports of python modules

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, module

I am deploying a flask app to Heroku but the app is crashing. In the log, I notice two things that ketch my attention:

> app[web.1]: [2021-07-21 16:50:59 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

My Procfile looks like this:

> web: gunicorn --chdir app app:app

The second issue, which I think is the root of the problem, is that in production, my relative imports are not being recognized (file structure below):

> app[web.1]: File "/app/app/app.py", line 13, in < module > 
> app[web.1]: from .models import ( 
> app[web.1]: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

This is my (simplified) file structure in my development environment:

> backend/ 
> |-- .git/ 
> |-- Procfile 
> |-- __ init __.py 
> |-- app/ 
> |---- | __ init __.py 
> |---- | app.py 
> |---- | models.py 
> |---- | auth/ 
> |-------- | __ init __.py 
> |-------- | auth.py

As you can see, I have added __ init __.py files in all directories to make them packages/sub-packages. The app runs in development. This is a snapshot of how I run my relative imports in app.py:

```
from .models import (
db,
setup_db,
...
)
```

When I inspect my file structure in Heroku, I see that the directory 'backend' does not exist. It is replaced by 'app', but it does still have the __ init __.py that is present in 'backend', so does the app/app package.

After running bash in Heroku, you can see my above statement:

```
~ $ ls
app  __init__.py  Procfile  requirements.txt  runtime.txt  test
~ $ cd app
~/app $ ls
app.py  auth  functions.py  __init__.py  manage.py  migrations  models.py  requirements.txt
```

I guess I can try to containerize the app and deploy it as an image to avoid differences between development and production environments. But before I take that route, I wonder if anyone knows how to solve this issue in production?

Comment: You can try using `from app.models...` where app is the parent package.

Comment: @charchit the app crashes in development with that solution. And in production I get this error: `app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'.` any other suggestion?

Comment: UPDATE from my previous comment. for the "failed to find attribute" error, I changed my Procfile to `web: gunicorn app.app:app`  and the app runs now. My import in production looks like this: `from modules ...` However, it only runs in production. It crashes in development with a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Comment: I think you are using factory design in a wrong way, you should use it like this https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/. A good example how factory design works https://github.com/mathewsjoyy/Flask-Portoflio-Blog-Website,

Comment: @charchit thank you. Great resources. I will definitely look more into Blueprints. I am compering the core structure of the GitHub repository you sent me with mine, and they look fairly similar. Obviously, I am talking only about the core components (where app.py, models.py, Procfile, etc) are located relative to the root directory. Which leads me to believe that that's not what is causing my problem. If you disagree, please share your reasoning.

Comment: Every one has procfile,requirements.txt on root directory who is deploying to github. But in your case I see there are two requirements.txt and also you have a app file in app folder which is again a folder named app. Will it not create confusion. I suggest you to restructure code. If you want I can help.

Comment: @charchit Yes, I had not seen the second requirements.txt. I am making some architectural changes and created a couple of git branches for experimentation. Would love for you to keep and eye on it and give me feedback. What's the best way to stay in touch with you outside of here? fard@outlook.com is my email.

Comment: You can contact me on discord `charchit#8198`. It's a better place and I can help you out there if you want.

Comment: What does your create_app look like?

Answer (score 1):

I restructured the architecture of my project and now it works. Thank you @charchit for your insights. They led me to the answer.

Here is what I did:

> backend/ 
> |-- .gitignore 
> |-- Procfile 
> |-- requirements.txt 
> |-- run.py 
> |-- app/ 
> |---- | __ init __.py 
> |---- | models.py 
> |---- | auth/ 
> |-------- | __ init __.py 
> |-------- | auth.py

**Changes:**

1. removed __init__py from backend
2. removed `backend/app/app.py` and copy the content of `app.py` to `backend/app/__init__.py`
3. added `run.py` to `backend/` which is where .git is and where Heroku will look for the app.

run.py looks like this:

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

4. modified Procfile to: `web: gunicorn run:app`
5. in app/**init**.py, the import looks like this

`from .models import db, setup_db, Subject...` 
`from .auth.auth import AuthError, requires_auth` 
`etc ...`

**Now the app runs both locally and on production without any conflicts within its modules. Wohoo!!!**